# matlab OOP - evaluate dependent property without call, for error handling

Tags: matlab, oop, properties, evaluate

How to check whether a dependent property (e.g. have_error) meets a certain condition (e.g.=true) without calling this property? 
Many of my functions could set the dependent property have_error true. In this case I would use 'return' to stop calculation in the main code. I don't want to evaluate have_error after every function I use.

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Comment: Maybe instead of setting a flag you just [`throw` a `MException`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mexception.throw.html), then [`catch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html) it where appropriate?

Comment: That doesn't sound like a great pattern, can you post an MCVE to demonstrate how you want to use this?

Comment: I agree with @Dan You need to post some code. Nothing should be "setting" the dependent property.